# Train Accuracy vs Test Accuracy vs Confusion matrix

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, accuracy, confusion-matrix, classifier

After I developed my predictive model using Random Forest I get the following metrics:

```
        Train Accuracy ::  0.9764634601043997
        Test Accuracy  ::  0.7933284397683713
         Confusion matrix  [[28292  1474]
                            [ 6128   889]]
```

This is the results from this code:

```
  training_features, test_features, training_target, test_target, = train_test_split(df.drop(['bad_loans'], axis=1),
                                                  df['target'],
                                                  test_size = .3,
                                                  random_state=12)
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
trained_model = clf.fit(training_features, training_target)
trained_model.fit(training_features, training_target)
predictions = trained_model.predict(test_features)      

Train Accuracy: accuracy_score(training_target, trained_model.predict(training_features))
Test Accuracy: accuracy_score(test_target, predictions)
Confusion Matrix: confusion_matrix(test_target, predictions)
```

However I'm getting a little confuse to interpret and explain this values.

What exactly this 3 measures tell me about my model?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, here your confusion matrix (and in general) when it is reported is based on test data. Because you could have it even for training data that you built the mode on.

Comment: I've some doubts to calculate this measures. Why for Train Accuracy put :(training_target, trained_model.predict(training_features) and not (training_target, trained_model.predict(test_target)?

Comment: The accuracy just for Class 1 is 77/94 ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Definitions

- Accuracy: The amount of correct classifications / the total amount
  of classifications.
- The train accuracy: The accuracy of a model on examples it was constructed on.
- The test accuracy is the accuracy of a model on examples it hasn't seen.
- Confusion matrix: A tabulation of the predicted class (usually
  vertically) against the actual class (thus horizontally).

## Overfitting

What I would make up of your results is that your model is **overfitting**. You can tell that from  the large difference in accuracy between the test and train accuracy. Overfitting means that it learned rules  specifically for the train set, those rules do not generalize well beyond the train set.

Your confusion matrix tells us how much it is overfitting, because your largest class makes up over 90% of the population. Assuming that you test and train set have a similar distribution, any useful model would have to score more than 90% accuracy:  A simple 0R-model would. Your model scores just under 80% on the test set.

## In depth look at the confusion matrix

If you would look at the confusion matrix relatively (in percentages) it would look like this:

```
               Actual    TOT
               1    2
Predicted 1 | 77% | 4% | 81%  
Predicted 2 | 17% | 2% | 19%
TOT         | 94% | 6% |
```

You can infer from the total in the first row that your model predicts **Class 1** 81% of the time, while the actual occurrence of **Class 1** is 94%. Hence your model is underestimating this class. *It could be the case that it learned specific (complex) rules on the train set, that work against you in the test set.*

It could also be worth noting that even though the false negatives of **Class 1** (17%-point, row 2, column 1)) are hurting your overall performance most, the false negatives of **Class 2** (4%-point, row 1 column 2) are actually more common with respect to the total population of the respective classes (94%, 6%). This means that your model is bad at predicting **Class 1**, but even worse at predicting **Class 2**. The accuracy just for **Class 1** is 77/99 while the accuracy for **Class 2** is 2/6.

Comment: Voted up for good answer. Maybe for educational purposes that would be better if you could elaborate on "how much it is overfitting" base on the actual confusion matrix elements. I am also curious to learn more.

Comment: I added a more in depth look, let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: So, for example when I'm getting this confusion matirx: 
Train Accuracy ::  0.8147735305312381
Test Accuracy  ::  0.8086616099828725
 Confusion matrix  [[9870   16]
                             [2330   45]]

It says that My model only have a precision of 73%

Comment: That confusion matrix would correspond to your test accuracy. (9870 + 45)/(9870+2330+16+45) = 0.80866161

Comment: @SvanBalen nice pedagogic answer. What is a "0R-model"? does it go by any other names?

Comment: ZeroR is a lot easier to Google :)